# How to rename rails app, folder and git remote repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bitbucket

I have a rails app called `appname` and a remote repo at bitbucket with the same name. I would like to rename it to `another_name`.

So far, I've tried changing the remote repo's name to `another_name`, tried `git push` and it fails. I didn't try renaming the rails app & its folder though, being afraid that something might break.

What's the right step to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename your remote repository, you also have to update the remote's URL in your local git repo:

```
git remote set-url origin https://new-url-here
```

You can rename the local folder freely without any side-effects.

Comment: Isn't `git set-url` made for this case? `git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]`

Comment: Did'nt know about that! Thanks. I've updated my initial answer.

Comment: Should I rename the local folder first or run the above command first?

Comment: You can also rename the local folder but it's not necessary.

Comment: Should I rename the folder using `git mv appname another_name` or can I just use Windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Agis' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10947185/294869), this is how I did it:

1. Rename the repo in bitbucket website to `another_name`.
2. Run `git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myname/another_name.git` (I'm using SSH instead of HTTPS)
3. Rename my rails' app local folder to `another_name` using Windows explorer.
4. Open up text editor, use the `find all` feature to find all the files that contain the old name & replace the old name with the new one.